# Meteor/MongoDB: Pulling an element from two sub-arrays with a single command?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have an element with the following structure:

```
{
 modules: [
    {
     type: "group1",
     readers:["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"],
     writers:["user1", "user2", "user6", "user7"]
    },
    {
     type: "group2",
     readers:["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"],
     writers:["user1", "user2", "user6", "user7"]
    }
   ]
 }
```

I have a varying (but capped) number of objects in the modules array, and I want to remove `"user1"` from all of the reader and writer groups with the fewest number of calls. I've tried this:

```
  Collection.update({"modules.writers": user_id}, {$pull: {"modules.$.writers":user_id}});
  Collection.update({"modules.readers": user_id}, {$pull: {"modules.$.readers":user_id}});
```

It only removes the user from one of the modules. Do I need to use a new call for each object in the module array, or is there a way to do it all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a second key-value pair to your `$pull` object.

```
Collection.update(
  {$or: [
    "modules.writers": user_id,
    "modules.writers": user_id
  },
  {$pull: {
    "modules.$.writers": user_id,
    "modules.$.readers": user_id
  }}
);
```

If the specified element you want to pull is not defined, it is ignored.

[Read more in the mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull)